# React routing - are component state values preserved, and can useReducer be used with some useState variables in it?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am new to React, and I am planning to build a simple task management site using React which I am having a couple of confusions about. Below is a wireframe I made for the project:

[image: My simple task management site's wireframe]

My first confusion is regarding the task number field which I want the system to auto-generate. For simplicity, I want the task number to start with 001 which will automatically increase by 1 after a new task is created. For now, I don't care about preserving the value after the user leaves or refreshes the site. So I think I would set `taskNumber` to be a state variable to keep track of its value. However, as I want to show the list of all created tasks on another page, I wonder about if routing to another page for showing the tasks would reset the value in `taskNumber`. After doing some searches, I still failed to find an answer to it.

If the value in `taskNumber` will not be preserved when the user goes to the page which shows all tasks, is there any recommended way for preserving this kind of value across different pages on a website? By that I mean using only front-end and React.

I am also puzzled about whether using the `useReducer` hook would be a good idea for getting the user's input for the task information. My initial idea is to create a state object for the `useReducer` hook which will contain every piece of information of the task:

```
const initialState = {
  taskNum: taskNum, //will start at 001  
  taskTitle: "", //empty by default
  importance: 1, //1 stands for trivial, 2 is normal, 3 is important, and 4 is highly important
  description: "", //empty by default
  taskState: taskState, //will be set as another state variable
  startTime: getTime, //will be a function for getting the date and time
  endTime: null, //not set until task is completed
  awaitNotes: null, //disabled unless task state is awaiting
};
```

However, it seems that embedding some state variables in a `useReducer` hook is unheard of and not right.

I am mainly stuck at these two points right now. I hope somebody can clear up my confusion about them and provide me with some hints as to what knowledge in React I may also need for building this project (is knowing basic React hooks enough?) Thank you very much for your kind help.

Comment: You can use `redux` or `react context` since you wish to make the state as a global object.

Comment: If you need to refer to some "common state" then the solution/pattern is to [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). If your app becomes more complex then solutions like React Context API and react-redux can help. You'll likely need to also persist your app state to local storage so upon page/app reloads you can populate your state with the saved data. If you aren't familiar with the reducer pattern then I suggest sticking to regular state, i.e. `useState`, keeping each chunk of data in it's own slice of state.

Comment: _I wonder about if routing to another page for showing the tasks would reset the value_ To simplify the answer to this question, it's all about which component the state belongs to. If that component ever unmounts from the virtual DOM (as opposed to just re-rendering without unmounting), then yes the state will be reset. This is why "global" state is usually implemented as a context provider at the top of your application, because it will never unmount due to its location at the top of the virtual DOM.